# make child widget get the input keypress with urwid on python

Tags: python, widget, keypress, urwid

I can make a widget inside another widget, as example an `urwid.Frame` father could have as `body` an `urwid.Pile` widget as child.
In this situation, the father should process some input keys when the child have to treat some specific others keys.

Like in this functional example:

```
import urwid


class NewFrame(urwid.Frame):
    def __init__(self, givenBody):
        super().__init__(urwid.Filler(givenBody, "top"))

    def keypress(self, size, key):
        if key  in ('f'):
            print("We are in NewFrame object")

        return super(NewFrame, self).keypress(size, key)


class NewPile(urwid.Pile):
    def __init__(self, givenList):
        super().__init__(givenList)

    def keypress(self, size, key):
        if key  in ('p'):
            print("We are in NewPile object")

        return super(NewPile, self).keypress(size, key)



master_pile = NewPile([
    urwid.Text("foo"),
    urwid.Divider(u'─'),
])


frame = NewFrame(master_pile)

loop = urwid.MainLoop(frame)
loop.run()
```

When I press <kbd>f</kbd> I could see the `Text` widget “We are in NewFrame”. But when I press <kbd>p</kbd>, the `NewPile` text doesn’t appear and nothing happens.

So, how could I make the child widget get input keys, especially when they are not matched by the `.keypress()` method of the parent?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can read from the documentation (http://urwid.org/manual/widgets.html#pile-widgets) a Pile widget is only selectable when it contains another selectable widget (which it doesn't in your example).

You should be able to override this behavior in your subclass by overriding `selectable()` to make it always selectable.

I think Urwid will never call `keypress` when a widget is not selectable, because widgets are only required to implement `keypress` when thet are selectable (http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html#urwid.Widget.selectable).

Answer (score 0):

In NewFrame's keypress() method call master_pile.keypress(), as below:

```
def keypress(self, size, key):
    if key  in ('f'):
        print("We are in NewFrame object")

    #return super(NewFrame, self).keypress(size, key)
    master_pile.keypress(size, key)
```

Comment: But in any case `size` would be wrong for `master_pile` right? This doesn't seem the "right" way to do it, if such way ever exists...